# .wav will not play in .exe

Tags: c++, audio, exe, wav

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("flip.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
    system("pause");
}
```

This code works perfectly. Self explanatory as to what it does. When I debug in VS2012 Express IDE, everything compiles and the audio plays. Save, close, go to debug file, press .exe, the cmd pops up but the audio doesn't play. Open the IDE again and debug, and works fine. Save, close, press .exe again and still nothing. What factor am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Try running directly from the command-line.

Comment: The applications working directory when being run in the IDE (Visual Studio) is by default not where the executable file is located. So when you double-click the executable to run it, the problem is that the program can't find the audio file, something which you do not check for.

Comment: Did both, still nothing.

Comment: Nothing what? No error message? As @JoachimPileborg suggested: is your `flip.wav` file in the same directory as your executable?

Comment: @Reticulated Spline: That did it! Sticking the audio file in the same folder as the .exe solved the problem! Thank you!